# Print multiple (dynamic div) pages with one window.print window - Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few rows data displaying (with JSP) in a table with last column checkbox, which allows to select multiple check boxes to print the rows. when hit print, it should prepare the data in Div and print. It is working fine by invoking window.Print() each time but I would like to invoke window.print() only once means one popup window to hit "Print" should take care of printing multiple pages for the number of selected checkboxes(records).

Could you help if any Jquery or JavaScript code which can handle this.

------------updated Question with code snippet ------------

```
function printNote()
{
    var id = 0;
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () 
    {
        id = id + 1;
        if($(this).attr("checked"))
        {
            document.getElementById("prntEmploeeFirstName").innerHTML = document.getElementById("prntEmploeeFirstName" + id).innerHTML;
            document.getElementById("prntEmploeeLastName").innerHTML = document.getElementById("prntEmploeeLastName" + id).innerHTML;   
            document.getElementById("prntEmployeeSalary").innerHTML = document.getElementById("prntEmployeeSalary" + id).innerHTML; 
            document.getElementById("printVersionEmployeeData").style.display = ''; 
            window.print();
        }
    });
}
```

Here I created the DIV which is Display None all the time,

```
<div id="printVersionEmployeeData" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

but in the Style sheet, on media print this Div is display show and rest of the page disply none

@media print {

```
Hide other Divs on the page.
```

}

This above code is working fine where it opens window print box to select the print for each given check box. 
for example If I have 10 or 20 emploee records I should hit 20 times to print each emploee deatil on separate page.
Is it possible to achieve to print multiple pages with one Print (window) click?

I tried having one more MainDiv which holds all these individual Divs data and print at the end, but I'm getting the results on the same page

```
document.getElementById("printVersionAllEmployeeData").innerHTML+=(document.getElementById ("printVersionEmployeeData").innerHTML);
document.getElementById("printVersionAllEmployeeData").innerHTML+='</br></br>';
```

Can I have array which has holds all these Divs and pass it to print at the end? I dont have much knowlegd on Jquery and Javascript. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Um, we have no clue what *"it should prepare the data in Div and print"* means. What data, what div. Show your code that works with one.

Comment: I have updated with code snippet